# TYPO3 8.7 is it possible to output a specific page with multiple url path s

Tags: url, typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm trying to integrate a vue.js application into a typo3 page.

I have a full functional TYPO3 instance where I can create own pages, edit the content and more. Now I want to add an existing vue.js application within this page.

Therefore I created an extension which added all necessary resources (js, css) and added an own content type which controls the integrations and configurations. The content type outputs a vue.js entry point. So far everything works. Smaller vue.js applications works as they should.

Now comes the challenge: When I want to create a more complex application which relies on the router functionality, I run into a problem.

Let's assume, I integrate my application into the page `/shop` and my application tries to render a product under `/shop/product/some-id`. This doesn't work. The URL processing is done by TYPO3 (as designed).

I tried to find a solution within the documentation but I'm not sure what I should search. I need a way to output the same page (`/shop`) regardless the following path. Does someone have a hint?

Comment: Not completely sure if I understood you problem right, but what about using rewriting in e.g. .htaccess like "add ?type=123 to every path starting with /shop" ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://medium.com/@rorywom5/symfony-4-3-vue-vuerouter-spa-fab618104d5. Notice that it will be easier to integrate this with TYPO3v9 which also uses Symfony Routing.

Comment: @TobiasGaertner i don't have controll over all url paths. I use vue.js as a fronend for shopware and shopware use to send emails with a fixed url structure.

Comment: @MathiasBrodala Typo3v9 is currently not an option. I'm working on a customer system and the customer do not want to update because the developer before me integrate a lot of stuff and nobody knows how this stuff works and what could go wrong with an update.

Comment: @TobiasGaertner i think that i missunderstood your answer. Is is indeed possible to do rewriting in the .htaccess, but I want to check out all typo3 solutions first. I want to understand how the routing works and if it's possible to trigger the rendering on another way. Maybe I have somehow add routes to realurl or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Within TYPO3 v8 is it possible to use the realurl extension for this purpose.

It is possible to define an own decode preprocessing function and analyse the current url.

```
 $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['decodeSpURL_preProc'][] = RealUrlManipulation::class . '->decodeSpURL_preProc';
```

Within this method is it possible to change the url for TYPO3 inner processing and set it to an known url.